# An embedded database server, which can be connected to over network

Tags: database, .net

I require an embedded database server(RDBMS or Document) which I can start within the current application process, which can be connected to over network for .Net. Do you have any recommendations?

```
ex. Starting the embedded within application
DBServer.Start("127.0.0.1:8888", SercurityOptions);
```

```
ex. Connecting to the server 
DBClient.Connect("ServerIPAddress:8888", Credentials);
```

Reason I require the server to be embedded is that the user requires application to have no installation components for the database engine. Also to have very small footprint compared to full fledged solutions. I've come across RavenDB however the server looks like it requires .Net core to run. VistaDB is the other option I've seen.

I do not have any experience with above software, nor embedded servers which runs within the application process. Would you have any experience or other recommendations?

Comment: Sounds like Sqlite is your best,maybe only, option